# output JSON with header field? (as ID of dataset)

Tags: php, json

I am currently doing the below in PHP; to convert a CSV file to usable JSON. This is working.... however,

```
  $tmpName = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];

    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "/files/locations/");

    $fh = fopen($tmpName, "r");

    $csvData = array();
    $keys = fgetcsv($fh, 0, ",");
    while (($row = fgetcsv($fh, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $csvData[] = array_combine($keys, $row);
    }
    // echo json_encode($csvData);
    file_put_contents("/files/locations/locations.json",json_encode($csvData))
```

It is outputting the JSON like this:

```
{"Zipcode":"90210","City":"Something","Primary State":"Utah","County Code":"49530","County":"Loudoun"}
```

I would like the Zipcode field and it's value to be the header. So, like below, so I can use the Zipcode value as the ID of the data set. Is this possible?

```
   {
    "Zipcode":"90210": { 
        "City":"Something",
        "Primary State":"Utah",
        "County Code":"49530",
        "County":"Loudoun"
    }
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: You could have `{"90210": {...}, "02474": { ... }, ...}`

Comment: @Barmar gotchya, is there anyway to organize it like this; or is this something I'd handle with the more front-end JS when grabbing the results?

Comment: Zipcode is the property and can't have a string value and an object value.

Comment: you'd need the value of "Zipcode" to be an array or object: `{"Zipcode": [{"90210" : {...}}, {"98107": {...}}, ...]}` or like Barmar said, `{"Zipcode": {"90210" : {...}, "98107": {...}, ...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of pushing the row onto the array, assign to an array key.

```
$csvData[$row[0]][] = array_combine($keys, $row);
```

This assumes the zip code is in the first field in the row (as it appears to be from your example of the original JSON).

Using `[]` makes each zip code entry an array of locations. So the result will look like:

```
{ "90210": [
    {
        "Zipcode": "90210",
        "City":"Something",
        "Primary State":"Utah",
        "County Code":"49530",
        "County":"Loudoun"
    }]
}
```

If you don't want the zip code to be redundantly included in the array elements, you can remove it from the key and values.

```
$keys = array_slice($keys = fgetcsv($fh, 0, ","), 1);
```

and

```
$zip = array_shift($row);
$csvData[$zip][] = array_combine($keys, $row);
```

Comment: So, this worked... but here is the kicker... IT REMOVED THE DUPLICATES.. I have a few entries that have the same Zipcode that was used as the header key, so then it just took one and remove the others in my json

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys in an associative array.

Comment: If there can be duplicates, you should make each element an array of all of them.

Comment: I've changed the answer to use `[]` in the assignments to make an array of objects in each zipcode.